# Simple jQuery Count Up timer help please

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to make a simple count up timer in jQuery... this sort of works but is adding the numbers to the end of '0000' and I want it to go `'0001' '0002' '0003'` etc...

This is all happening in the jQuery `onReady` scope.

```
var i = '0000'
var timer = function doSomething ( )
{
    i = i+= 1
    $('.counter').text(i);
    console.log(i);

}
setInterval (timer, 1000 );
```

Comment: Advice: 1. Use semi-colons to end your lines. They are optional, but not really (Read Javascript the Good Parts for why) 2. Always put your braces on the same line. This is not a style thing, braces on a new line can cause weird errors. 3. Your function currently has 2 names, just use one - you can do `function() {...` 3. you are scanning the whole document each time for `$(.counter)`, you should store that in a variable so that you don't have to scan.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer Understanding the situations in which a line break *doesn't* end a statement is more important than always blindly using semicolons, because even those of use who use semicolons will still include some statements that span multiple lines. In these cases, putting a semicolon at the end won't save you. See [this great article](http://blog.izs.me/post/2353458699/an-open-letter-to-javascript-leaders-regarding)

Comment: The minutiae of line breaks and semi-colons wasn't what I was going for here, but I appreciate the advice.

Comment: Yes of course it's not, that's why I posted a comment rather than an answer. Your issue was with type coercion - there are some good answers below. @benekastah - Absolutely, understanding what is really going on is helpful, as a rule, sticking to semi-colons will get you out of 99% of weird cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code is appending to a string, not addition to a number. It essentially looks like

```
i = '0000' + 1, i = '00001' + 1, i = '000011' + 1 ...
```

and so on. You'll need to keep it integer based to continue adding to the number. Here's an example with the formatting it looks like you wanted.

```
var pad = function(n) { return (''+n).length<4?pad('0'+n):n; };

jQuery.fn.timer = function() {
    var t = this, i = 0;
    setInterval(function() {
        t.text(pad(i++));
    }, 1000);
};

$('#timer').timer();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jDaTK/

Answer (score 3):

Your "i" variable needs to be an integer. You can format it how you like when you want to print it somewhere.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var i = 0;
    var target = $('.counter');
    var timer = function doSomething ( )
    {
        i++;

        var output = pad(i,4);
        target.text(output);
        console.log(output);

    }
    setInterval (timer, 1000 );
});


    function pad(number, length) {

        var str = '' + number;
        while (str.length < length) {
            str = '0' + str;
        }
        return str;

    }​
```

Comment: This is actually very elegant. Thank you very much for showing me. Is this scanning the entire doc each time it updates, looking for the 'counter' div?

Comment: It is. In general, I wouldn't worry too much about performance issues unless you actually encounter them. If you wanted to avoid this, you could store the jquery selector in a variable like this (make sure to do it outside the timer function): var target = $('.counter');  then you could say target.text(output) to update it. I had edited the code to show this.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something more like this:

```
// Make sure Date.now exists in your environment
Date.now = Date.now || function () { return Number(new Date()); };

var time = 0,
start = Date.now(),
intervalId;

intervalId = setInterval(function () {
  var seconds, display;
  // get the exact time since the timer was started
  time = Date.now() - start;
  // get the number or seconds, rounded down
  seconds = Math.floor(time / 1000);
  display = '' + seconds;

  // pad the beginning of your display string with zeros
  while (display.length < 4) {
    display = "0" + display;
  }
  console.log(display);
}, 100);
```

`setInterval` is not exact. This code ensures that while the display could be up to nearly a second off (in theory), the actual time you are tracking is always the exact amount of time that has elapsed since you started the timer. But this code would update the display about once every tenth of a second, so it's not likely to ever be off more than a few milliseconds.

From here you can figure out smarter ways to update the display to ensure you have the level of accuracy you need. If this needs to be pretty accurate, then you could make sure you are displaying to the tenth of the second.

Comment: This works (and thank you greatly) but feels so weird. Why do we need to pad anything. Can't we take a valid number of 0000 and add one to it for 0001? without making parts of this a string?

Comment: The number `0000` is just `0`, so `0000` should be a string if you want the leading zeroes. `'0000' + 1` just appends `1` to the end of the string, giving you `'00001'`. However, `1 + 1` gives you `2`, which is the correct value, but it doesn't display with leading zeroes. The solution is to calculate the value as numbers, but then display it as a string. In this solution, the value will be turned into a string, and then will have zeros appended to the beginning until the length of the string is 4. At that point, you have the proper value with the proper amount of leading zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

I really recommend the [jQuery CountUp](http://flwtb.co/NyRiSl) plugin. I tried a number of Javascript counters and this was one of the easiest to implement and came with lots of goodies:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#counter').countUp({
            'lang':'en', 'format':'full', 'sinceDate': '22/07/2008-00::00';
        });
    });
</script>        

<div id="counter"></div>
```

Comment: Hey, the link is not working. It's throwing 404! error.